# Android twitter tweet sharing

Tags: android

I am working in an android application and I want to share a tweet(
 http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/291-twitter-integration-in-your-android-application) to twitter from my android application. I have created a twitter application in twitter developers an I have integrated the CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_SECRET and the first day it worked correctly and the second day it causes error Error during OAUth retrieve request token(OAUth communication exception).

Please help me.

Comment: can u share ur code and also api key and secret bcz let we have to check in our code.suggest where the problem is

Comment: Hi Khan, Thanks for your reply. You will be able to download the code from this link https://github.com/ddewaele/AndroidTwitterSample      My Consumer key cXk9h04O6MFXUZYBYGTPcQ and Consumer secret  qHB39vEW2QINRhxI6oQJ8rr4phGC25VEgZUctqFEOOk

Comment: let me check this key and inform u if it works or not and what changes needed as i got from it

Comment: the problem is in key generation as i got let u inform

Comment: ok.Thanks. Please let me informed. Thanks again

Comment: Hi Khan, I found that I have created a new Consumer key and Consumer secret which has permissions Read, write, and direct messages . Still it causes the same error. My new Consumer key M9hFcEkZI1aUHe0FA9aOzw and Consumer secret 8rREiwyKjSWf02LyloPeS41kC6yLfqsFAvSejQs. Please help me.

Comment: are u able to single tweet first time or not able to post first time too

Comment: First time I am able to tweet, but after some time that i get the error OAUth communication exception with the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit your application permissions to read and write
and save your application profile on twitter..
then try again

Comment: Hi Deepak Swami, I found that I have created a new Consumer key and Consumer secret which has permissions Read, write, and direct messages . Still it causes the same error. My new Consumer key M9hFcEkZI1aUHe0FA9aOzw and Consumer secret 8rREiwyKjSWf02LyloPeS41kC6yLfqsFAvSejQs. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Use This..

```
StatusesService statusesService = TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient().getStatusesService();
Call<Tweet> tweetCall = statusesService.update(text, null, false, null, null, null, false, false, null);
tweetCall.enqueue(new Callback<Tweet>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Result<Tweet> result) {
        Log.d("result", result.data.idStr);
    }



    @Override
    public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
        hideProgressDialogResult();
        exception.printStackTrace();

    }
});
```